# How to prevent Nearest Neighbour Interpolation in scipy Image.resize module to not normalize the images in scene parsing annotations

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, deep-learning

I am trying to reduce the dimensions of my image using `PIL.Image.NEAREST` interpolation in `Image.resize()`. The problem is that these images are annotations for a scene parsing task. So the pixel values are all integers representing classes. So that is why I choose nearest neighbour interpolation. But the problem is scipy's resize module seems to normalize the images after interpolation and that leads to different non integer values for my pixels(which do not represent any class). So is there any way to prevent that or any other module in python to help me achieve the proper nearest neighbor interpolation, where the interpolated pixels are the actual pixel values chose from the neighbouring pixels without normalization?

edit:
sample code to reproduce the issue:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imresize

x = np.load('scale.npy')
y = imresize(x, (300, 400), 'nearest')
```

Here all the values in x lie between(1,151). So this interpolation should preserve that. But I see new and big values all over.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of your code?  You have mentioned both `Image.resize()` and "scipy's resize module", so it is not clear exactly how you are resizing your image.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have tried `img = scipy.misc.imresize(img, (width, height), 'nearest')` as well as  `img.resize((width, height), Image.NEAREST)` where the second example uses PIL.Image.

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?  A simple test with `scipy.misc.imresize(img, (width, height), 'nearest')` worked for me.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser . I have upload my numpy array that I am trying to rescale at this google drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx3v5czGESz1dzZ1cTM4ZXFlYVk/view?usp=sharing                   . You can just load it using numpy.load('scale.npy'). Note that all elements in this array are between 1-150. But when you apply `scipy.misc.imresize(img, (width, height), 'nearest')` , where `width =300, height=400`, you will see out of range values.